# Semantic-Ui Dropdown - Trigger call for remote data

Tags: frontend, dropdown

I have an odd necessity at my current project. I am using Semantic-Ui as a front-end framework.

One of my views includes semantic-ui dropdown component and this component gets it's datas from remote source. What I need is to call remote source manually. When I start texting, dropdown component calls to remote api and get datas back nicely, but I failed at triggering calls manually.

My question is, how can i call remote content at dropdown's onchange event.

My current code is (#searchInput is id of my input):

```
 onChange: function (val) {
                $('#searchInput').trigger('change');
            }
```

Thanks for your helps and kind

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Dear Toby, thanks for your advices. I already read "How To Ask" guide and before submited my question here, I already gave a chance to Github develeopment page and asked to contributors. What i tried so far is regardless to this question (my opinion) because they already failed. I need exact advise from experts. But I will edit my answer and share last shot. Thanks again!